# Error with FileOutputStream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Invalid file path

Tags: java

I have the following function that copies part of a file and creates a new file. This is being passed in the parameters of a `fileEntry` and a `fileObj`. The `fileEntry` is the file it is copying from and the `fileObj` is the file it is writing to.

```
private void getFile(FileEntry fileEntry, File fileObj) throws IOException {
        this.file.seek(fileEntry.offset + this.fileblock);
        byte[] b = new byte[(int) fileEntry.size];
        this.file.readFully(b);
        fileObj.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        try {
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileObj));
            bos.write(b);
            bos.flush();
            bos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(fileObj.getPath());
        }
    }
```

This function returns the following:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Invalid file path
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:204)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:160)
    at com.julianscode.GMAExtractor.getFile(GMAExtractor.java:97)
    at com.julianscode.GMAExtractor.getAllFiles(GMAExtractor.java:88)
    at com.julianscode.GMAExtractor.main(GMAExtractor.java:84)
/tmp/addonsExtract/ds_162581348/materials/vgui/ttt/icon_rg_defibrillator.png
```

The **bottom path** is the path that java says is invalid. Any ideas as to why the path is invalid and how I can fix it?

Comment: is the path a fully qualified path starting at /

Comment: Is `/tmp/addonsExtract/ds_162581348/materials/vgui/ttt/icon_rg_defibrillator.png` a directory?

Comment: Yeah, both paths are absolute.

Comment: No, that isn't a directory, but it turns out that it did create a file there.

Comment: The file isn't filled with anything though

Comment: If you look into the JDK source for `FileOutputStream` the exception is caused by `File.isInvalid()` (http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/io/File.java#185) returning true. What does `fileObj.getPath().indexOf('\u0000')` output?

Comment: Ah, I see, I wonder where that 0x00 character came from

Comment: Mark, if you want to answer, I'll accept.